# Using order by and direction with case when but error sorting by secondary column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Below works fine:

```
ORDER BY
 CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 1 AND @SortBy = 1 THEN announce.[Status] END ASC,
 CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 2 AND @SortBy = 1 THEN announce.[Status] END DESC 
 ...
```

What I want to do is apply a secondary sort order in each case which is same regardless of direction:

```
ORDER BY
 CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 1 AND @SortBy = 1 THEN announce.[Status] END ASC, announce.ID Desc,
 CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 2 AND @SortBy = 1 THEN announce.[Status] END DESC, announce.ID Desc,
 CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 1 AND @SortBy = 2 THEN announce.[Title] END ASC, announce.Date Desc,
 CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 2 AND @SortBy = 2 THEN announce.[Title] END DESC, announce.Date Desc
```

But above gives me error:

> A column has been specified more than once in order by list. Columns in order by list must be unique.

Comment: The `announce.ID` and `announce.Date`  is outside the Case and appears twice in the Order

Comment: Are you sure the first criteria worked fine? There's a missing comma between line 2 and line 3.

Comment: It seems like your @SortBy parameter is in relation to sorting by accounce.ID or announce.Date. Therefore, they should be removed from the CASE statements you have and put in their own respective CASE statements.

Comment: test this :
`ORDER BY
CASE 
WHEN @SortDirection = 1 AND @SortBy = 1 THEN announce.[Status] ASC
WHEN @SortDirection = 2 AND @SortBy = 1 THEN announce.[Status] DESC
END ,
announce.ID Desc ,
CASE 
WHEN @SortDirection = 1 AND @SortBy = 2 THEN announce.[Title] ASC
WHEN @SortDirection = 2 AND @SortBy = 2 THEN announce.[Title] DESC
END ,
announce.Date Desc
`

Comment: That doesn't work

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: it's syntax errors

Comment: Things like "it doesn't work" and "syntax error" are useless. What doesn't work? What is the syntax error? Providing information is paramount to finding a solution.

Comment: @riz try this : `ORDER BY
 CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 1 AND @SortBy = 1 THEN announce.[Status] END ASC,
 CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 2 AND @SortBy = 1 THEN announce.[Status] END DESC, announce.ID Desc,
 CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 1 AND @SortBy = 2 THEN announce.[Title] END ASC,
 CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 2 AND @SortBy = 2 THEN announce.[Title] END DESC, announce.Date Desc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to repeat the sort criteria for both directions if they're the same in either case, and they don't have to be right next to the other criteria either. Only one of the first four `CASE` expressions can possibly return true, and also only of the last two:

```
ORDER BY
 CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 1 AND @SortBy = 1 THEN announce.[Status] END ASC, 
 CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 2 AND @SortBy = 1 THEN announce.[Status] END DESC,
 CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 1 AND @SortBy = 2 THEN announce.[Title] END ASC, 
 CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 2 AND @SortBy = 2 THEN announce.[Title] END DESC,
 CASE WHEN @SortBy = 1 THEN announce.ID END DESC,
 CASE WHEN @SortBy = 2 THEN announce.Date END DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Given `@SortDirection = 1` and `@SortBy = 1` your sorts will translate to something like this:

```sql
--Sort 1
ORDER BY
 announce.[Status] ASC,
 NULL DESC
...
--Sort 2
ORDER BY
 announce.[Status] ASC, announce.ID Desc,
 NULL DESC, announce.ID Desc,
 NULL ASC, announce.Date Desc,
 NULL DESC, announce.Date Desc
```

Maybe try something like this:

```
ORDER BY
 CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 1 AND @SortBy = 1 THEN announce.[Status] END ASC,
 CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 2 AND @SortBy = 1 THEN announce.[Status] END DESC,
 CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 1 AND @SortBy = 2 THEN announce.[Title] END ASC,
 CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 2 AND @SortBy = 2 THEN announce.[Title] END DESC, 
announce.ID Desc,
announce.Date Desc
```

Comment: But ID should not sort before Date when SortBy = 2 (which will be important if ID and Date are not heavily correlated), and Date should probably not be sorted after ID when SortBy = 1 (though that is likely less consequential to the result, unless ID is not unique).